rheostat needed for running two 200W electric motors in parallel
I have an electric golf bag cart.  It has two 200 W motors and runs on 12 V battery.  The controller is bad, so I was thinking about rewiring the two motors in parallel and run them directly from the battery via a rheostat.  What rheostat do I need for this?  Thank you.
Or...do I just use a PWM like this?
Amazon advert link.

Are they DC or stepper motors? Do they have model numbers? What is the model of the controller? Repairable? if it's DC motors then 400W divide by 12V is 34Amps. that means plenty heat. Normal electronics is 3Amps max. A Rheostat/adjustable resistor will get super hot and will need cooling. So a DC voltage regulator that can handle 50Amps is way to go if you don't want to add a fan to keep it cool.

A PWM controller will be cheaper than a rheostat at that power level.

If they are DC motors then get 2x controllers (1 for each motor). Then you can steer with them as well if steering wheel gets stuck. 200 W divide by 12 V is 17 amps. So you will at least need a 20 amp DC-to-DC step-down buck voltage regulator. Consider fan cooling.
You need to replace the tiny variable resistors with larger variable resistors which must be soldered in.
30 amp Waterproof
DC to DC 20 A

This is not 1850. It's 2024. We haven't used rheostats to control DC motors in a long time. My advice to you is to replace the broken DC motor controller with an honest-to-goodness golfcart DC motor controller. It will perform significantly better than any rheostat you might be able to jury rig and will cost less. It will be more reliable than a open assembly module from Amazon.

Connect them in series to they have the same torque. it will make steering much easier.
Yes use a PWM controller.
